# PHP build html table with id

Tags: php, laravel, html-table

I use PHP (Laravel) and MySQL.

When I query the data from the database I get the following result:

[image: start]

The first column is the id. The second column is the column in the target table and the third column is the effective data.
One line should be created per id and the data should be written into the specified column. If there is no data, nothing should be done.
I wrote a @foreach-loop. But it writes a line for each entry:

[image: current]

The goal is that the table looks like this:

[image: goal]

I hope I have described my problem well enough.
Thank you

Comment: Add code to the question.

Comment: How have you got ids repeated with differing data? I suspect your query is faulty from the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all from data you need to filter your data so that you can easily print it into table. I am giving you example here in php; you can easily use the same logic to work with laravel.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'col' => 'a', 'data' => 'X'),
    array('id' => 2, 'col' => 'a', 'data' => 'Y'),
    array('id' => 2, 'col' => 'b', 'data' => 'Z'),
    array('id' => 3, 'col' => 'a', 'data' => 'X'),
    array('id' => 3, 'col' => 'b', 'data' => 'Y'),
    array('id' => 3, 'col' => 'c', 'data' => 'Z'),
);

$filterData = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $filterData[$val['id']][$val['col']] = $val['data'];
}

$html = '<table border="1">';
$html .= '<tr><th>id</th><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th></tr>';
if(!empty($filterData)) {
    foreach ($filterData as $kData => $value) {
        $a = isset($value['a']) ? $value['a'] : '';
        $b = isset($value['b']) ? $value['b'] : '';
        $c = isset($value['c']) ? $value['c'] : '';
        $html .= '<tr><td>'.$kData.'</td><td>'.$a.'</td><td>'.$b.'</td><td>'.$c.'</td></tr>';
    }
} else {
    $html .= '<tr><td colspan="4">No record found!</td></tr>';
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Great! Mark answer